# Null pointer exception while creating a custom robolectric shadow for UserManager

Tags: java, android, robolectric

In Robolectric 2.4, I need to create a custom shadow for android.os.UserManager class.

Following is the code to be tested:

```
private Bundle checkFoo() {
    UserManager userMgr = ((UserManager) getSystemService(Context.USER_SERVICE));
    Bundle restrictionsBundle = userMgr.getApplicationRestrictions("test-pkg_name");
    return restrictionsBundle;
}
```

Since there was no default ShadowUserManager provided by Robolectric in 2.4 I created following custom shadow UserManager class:

```
@Implements(UserManager.class)
public class ShadowUserManager {

@Implementation
public Bundle getApplicationRestrictions(String packageName) {
...
return new Bundle();
}
```

For above class I tried to shadow the constructor too as follows but IUserManager seems to be not available to import.

```
public void __constructor__(Context context, IUserManager usrMgr){
}
```

Following is the test code:

```
@RunWith(MyTestRunner.class)
@Config(shadows = {ShadowUserManager.class})
public class MyTestClass {
@Test
public void testFoo() {
    Bundle actualBundle = checkfoo();
    //assert actual and expected bundle
    ...
}
}
```

I believe I do not need to explicitly specify UserManager to be instrumented in my TestRunner's shouldInstrument() function as UserManger is in android.os package, which gets instrumented by default if shadow is available. (Though I tried this too but to no avail!!)

While running the test I always end up getting a null pointer in checkFoo() function when trying to call getApplicationRestrictions() on userMgr object. userMgr always end up being null. 
Any pointers to solve this is appreciated.

Or is there a way to mock the getSystemService() API in Android context to provide custom UserManager object?